# 1KB Grid - Dropdown Menu not shown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've got a problem with a dropdown menu. I think the troubles comes from the overflow:hidden;. I don't see the submenu of the dropdown. I use the 1KB Grid.

When I delete the overflow:hidden from the .container class, I can see a bit of the dropdown but not the whole one.

I'm pleased about a an info how I could fix it.

grid.css:

```
.grid_1         {width: 70px;}
.grid_2         {width: 160px;}
.grid_3         {width: 250px;}
.grid_4         {width: 340px;}
.grid_5         {width: 430px;}
.grid_6         {width: 520px;}
.grid_7         {width: 610px;}
.grid_8         {width: 700px;}
.grid_9         {width: 790px;}
.grid_10        {width: 880px;}
.grid_11        {width: 970px;}
.grid_12        {width: 1060px;}

.container      {margin: 0 10px 0 10px; overflow: hidden; float: left; display: inline;}
.row            {width: 1080px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; }
.row .row       {margin: 0 -10px 0 -10px; width: auto; display: inline-block;}
```

menu.css

```
nav                                 {float:right; margin-top:45px; position:relative; z-index:99; font-size:14px 1.4rem; text-transform:uppercase;}

nav .rex-navi1                      {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; float:right;}

nav .rex-navi1 li                   {float:left; margin-left:10px; background:#FF9;} 
nav .rex-navi1 li:hover             {background:#3F6;} 
nav .rex-navi1 li a                 {display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#fff; padding:6px 15px; height:20px; line-height:20px;}
nav .rex-navi1 li:hover a           {color:#383738;}
nav .rex-navi1 a.rex-current,
nav .rex-navi1 a.rex-active         {background:#FC9; color:#383738;}

nav .rex-navi2                      {position: relative; z-index:100px;}

nav li:hover .rex-navi2             {visibility:visible;}
nav li .rex-navi2                   {visibility: hidden; position:absolute; font-size:11px; font-weight:normal; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; background:#FFF;}                                 

nav .rex-navi2 li                   {background:#fff; clear:left; display:block; min-width:200px;}      
nav .rex-navi2 li a                 {color:#383738;  padding:5px 15px; }
nav .rex-navi2 li a:hover           {font-weight:bold; color:#DC002E;}
nav .rex-navi2 a.rex-current        {font-weight:bold;}
```

HTML Code:

```
div id="header">        
            <header class="row">
                    <section class="container grid_4">
                        <a href="/" alt="master bench logo"><img src="files/logo_header.png"/></a>
                    </section>
                    <nav class="container grid_8">
                        <ul class="rex-navi1">
                            <li class="rex-article-2 rex-normal"><a href="">xy</a></li>
                            <li class="rex-article-8 rex-current"><a class="rex-current" href="">xy</a></li>
                            <li class="rex-article-4 rex-normal"><a href="">xy</a>
                                <ul class="rex-navi2">
                                    <li class="rex-article-13 rex-normal"><a href="">xy</a></li>
                                    <li class="rex-article-12 rex-normal"><a href="">xy</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </header>
    </div><div id="main">   
            <article class="row">
                <article class="container grid_12">
                    here you will find some interesting information<br/>
                </article>
            </article>          

        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first off there are a few minor mistakes in what you have.

```
nav .rex-navi2 {position: relative; z-index:100px;} // z-index doesn't need px
nav {float:right; margin-top:45px; position:relative; z-index:99; font-size:14px 1.4rem; text-transform:uppercase;} // 1.4rem should be 1.4em
```

also in your html

```
           <li class="rex-article-12 rex-normal"><a href="">xy</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

should be

```
           <li class="rex-article-12 rex-normal"><a href="">xy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> // you forgot to close out your li, 
</ul>
```

and lastly I don't know what you intend, but I get the feeling that you might be using the article element wrong. (as you have `<article><article></article></article>`). An article should be able to stand on it's own http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/ for more about articles

Now to get to the actual problem. 
You have `overflow:hidden` for both the `.row` and `.container` while this helps clear the floats, it also acts to hide any content that would fall outside the row and container.
Undeniably that is one of the better methods to clear floats, however you could also use a clear div to do it (`.clear{clear:both;}` and add `<div class="clear"></div>` at the end of each row, instead of the overflow hidden), or the even more hacky clearfix method http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/